# Automation scripts: is it possible to find particular text on the screen?

Tags: java, testing, automation, screenshot

I am creating automated scripts using T-Plan Robot, a Java based tool which logs into an SUT machine.

Currently the way I'm handling where the mouse cursor should click is by using mini screenshots of locations using a "waittomatch" or "compareto" methods.

Example:

```
compareTo(new File[] { new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Google Drive\\Testing\\Automation\\Robot\\ImageTemplates\\LabelFirstName.png") }, "search2");
      if (getContext().getExitCode() > 0) {
          exit(1);
      } else {
mouseClick(new Point(getVariableAsInt("_COMPARETO_CLICK_X"), getVariableAsInt("_COMPARETO_CLICK_Y")));
      }
```

However, all these matches are elements I expect. Field labels don't change that often and stay the same, so the script always finds them.

The issue I'm facing now is I wish to find a particular applicant record on the screen after it has saved. It has a constantly changing name rather than a fixed one, so it's not a simple case of taking a screenshot and matching it. For example it adds a date and time on the end:

```
type("PrimaryApplicant_" + getVariableAsString("_CURDATE"), "100");
```

Is there a way of being able to move the mouse cursor to this exact text?

Maybe a way of storing this information as a string then matching it to what is on the screen at the time? How is this done?

Hope this makes sense. Pretty hard to explain without demonstrating it!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing major at the moment. I thought of another solution which wasn't part of taking a screen capture in the end, but I have come across the same issue again today which definitely can only be solved using what I have described.

Answer (score 0):

If the label identifier is always "PrimaryApplicant_ddmmyyyy" then you should be able to grab the label using some regex that just ignore the date unless I've misunderstood the problem? (I would have made this a comment rather than an answer, but I don't think I have enough reputation yet...)